# Full Screen Background Image behaves differently from network and local storage

Tags: react-native

I am trying to stretch a background-image to full screen.
Images seem to behave differently when fetched from Network and from Local storage.

This function does not stretch the image as requested (there is a white margin of around 70 pixels from the right):
This is my render() fundtion:

```
  var BackgroundImage = require('./images/logo_og.png');

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={[{flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch'}]}>
      <Image source={BackgroundImage} style={[{flex: 1}]} >
      </Image>
    </View>
  );
```

The same render function works well displaying the image being fetched from the network:

```
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={[{flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch'}]}>
      <Image source={{uri:'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} style={[{flex: 1}]} >
      </Image>
    </View>
  );
```

any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar issue was reported [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/950). Try setting the Image's width to `null`:

```
<Image source={BackgroundImage} style={[{flex: 1, width: null}]} >
```