# React Native require() network vs. static image resize

Tags: image, react-native, require, react-native-flexbox

How come when I use a network image,

```
<View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch'}}>
          <Image
           style={{flex: 1}}
           source={{uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}} />
</View>
```

it fills the page:
[image: Google logo stretched across screen]

but when I use require() for a static image:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch'}}>
 <Image
  style={{flex: 1}}
  source={require('./googlelogo.png')} />
</View>
```

it doesn't?
[image]

Running react-native 0.37.0. This code was added straight into a freshly `react-native init`-ed project, no 3rd party libraries or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you were having the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706127/full-screen-background-image-behaves-differently-from-network-and-local-storage).

Try setting the Image's width to `null`:

```
<Image
  style={{flex: 1, width: null}}
  source={require('./googlelogo.png')} />
```